# Invalid syntax in discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have made a discord bot in python which works fine. But now i wanted to implement a bad word filter. The bot will warn the person if he or she says a bad word. I also want it to be embedded. The error is on the last line (i.e. the await message.channel.send(embed=embedwarn). Where it says there's a invalid syntax, but I can't find it.

```
#bad words for the bot to detect
bad_words = ["Word1", "Word2"]

#send person a warning message
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == bot.user:
      return
    if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in bad_words):
      embedwarn=discord.Embed(title="Warning", description=f"Server: {member.name} \nReason: bad word")
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedwarn)
```

Comment: Try using the `discord.py` tag to get better answers! Also, could you send the full error message? Also, for your bad word detection, try ```if message.content.lower() in bad_words:``` for a more concise method.

Comment: The indentation is different in each of your if statements

Comment: @Sayse indeed, but that shouldn't give the invalid syntax error in the last line. If I'm right? It's fine for the if statements that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code wasn't properly indented.

```
if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in bad_words):
    embedwarn=discord.Embed(title="Warning", description=f"Server: {member.name} \nReason: bad word")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedwarn)
```